# Multiple request body error

Tags: wcf

Actual error on on client side while applying client behavior :

> Operation 'GetCurrentStreamPositionByStreamId' of contract
>   'IVideoService' specifies    multiple request body parameters to be
>   serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter
>   can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra
>   body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the
>   WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Specify uritemplate in webinvoke attribute over the method as:

```
       [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(
        Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "getcurrenttime/{managerid}/{streamid}")]
        DateTime GetRecordedVideoCurrentTime(string managerid,string streamid);
```

Comment: My Operation in contract :                                                [OperationContract]                                                         DateTime GetRecordedVideoCurrentTime(string managerid,string streamid);                                                                      as you can see input parameters are simple string not user classes. and i dont thinkthis is illegal in wcf